# Pandas: apply function: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'unicode'

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have the following data frame `df`:

```
name    event_time
------------------------------------------
Mary   [(S, 2017-12-03T03:40:20.000Z), (V, 2017-12-07T02:51:32.000Z)]
Peter  [(S, 2017-11-02T01:11:10.000Z), (V, 2017-11-19T07:23:12.000Z)]
Andy   [(S, 2017-12-01T10:31:15.000Z), (V, 2017-12-09T12:31:10.000Z)]
```

I then used the following code to find the time duration of the two elements in the `event_time` field:

```
df['duration'] = df.event_time.apply(lambda x:x[1][1]-x[0][1])
```

However, I got the following errors:

```
TypeError unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'unicode' 
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-7a191c6f2678> in <module>()
----> 1 df['duration'] = df.event_time.apply(lambda x:x[1][1]-x[0][1])

/opt/conda/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   2218         else:
   2219             values = self.asobject
-> 2220             mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   2221 
   2222         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/src/inference.pyx in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas/lib.c:62658)()

<ipython-input-7-7a191c6f2678> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 df['duration'] = df.event_time.apply(lambda x:x[1][1]-x[0][1])

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'unicode'
```

Any idea what I did wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: What is the type of each `df.event_time`? Is it a unicode string? It looks like you are trying to calculate a time difference. `x[1][1]` and `x[0][1]` are `unicode` in the `lambda`, which do not support the `-` operator.

Comment: It looks like you're pulling out two different dates in string format from your df, then you're trying to subtract one from the other, which you cannot do with these (unicode) strings. You probably need to convert the long string date format to some numerical value or data structure which you can then diff, if that's what you need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need select values by `str[]`, convert [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and subtract:

```
s1 = pd.to_datetime(df['event_time'].str[1].str[1])
s2 = pd.to_datetime(df['event_time'].str[0].str[1])
df['duration'] =  s1 - s2
print (df)
    name                                         event_time         duration
0   Mary  [(S, 2017-12-03T03:40:20.000Z), (V, 2017-12-07...  3 days 23:11:12
1  Peter  [(S, 2017-11-02T01:11:10.000Z), (V, 2017-11-19... 17 days 06:12:02
2   Andy  [(S, 2017-12-01T10:31:15.000Z), (V, 2017-12-09...  8 days 01:59:55
```